# Фрагменты остаются после того, как активность была убита и воссоздана заново

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, activity-life-cycle

0) Имеется активность у которой есть BottomNavigationView с двумя элементами меню. У активности присутствует контейнер, в котором проиходит замена фрагментов.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:baseActivity=".BaseActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Собственно, создаются 2 фрагмента:
- Класс **StartFragment** содержит одно TextView (т.е. ничего особенного);
- Класс **ListInFragment** содержит **RecyclerView с Адаптером** и в onCreate вызывается Toast с каким-то текстом. Т.е. тоже ничего особенного.
В принципе, структура приложения проста.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.d("test_logic", "BaseActivity: onCreate()");  

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

            // Устанавливаем стартовый фрагмент, передаем new StartFragment, при клике на второй пункт меню вызываем этот же фрагмент
            replaceFragment(new StartFragment());
        }  

        // Метод для замены фрагментов
        private replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container_base, fragment);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.d("test_logic", "BaseActivity: onRestart()");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("test_logic", "BaseActivity: onStart()");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("test_logic", "BaseActivity: onResume()");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("test_logic", "BaseActivity: onPause()");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("test_logic", "BaseActivity: onStop()");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("test_logic", "BaseActivity: onDestroy()");
}
}
```

1) При нажатии на второй элемент меню, первый фрагмент (StartFragment) заменяется вторым (ListInFragment):

```
public class ListInFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRvEvent;

    public ListInFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("test_logic", "ListInFragment: onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_in, null);

        Log.d("test_logic", "ListInFragment: onCreateView()");

         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Второй фрагмент стартовал", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mRvEvent = view.findViewById(R.id.event_rv);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRvEvent.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRvEvent.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        mRvEvent.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);
        mRvEvent.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mCurrentActivity,
                mLayoutManager.getOrientation())); 

        mRvEvent.setAdapter(new EventAdapter(mList));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("test_logic", "ListInFragment: onStop()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.d("test_logic", "ListInFragment: onDestroyView()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("test_logic", "ListInFragment: onDestroy()");
    }

    public class EventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.EventViewHolder> {
        // Заполняем RecyclerView  
    }
}
```

2) **Описание проблемы**
Я перехожу на второй фрагмент, сворачиваю приложение и со временем система убивает его процесс (onDestroy активности не вызывается). Когда с Недавних приложений я вызываю его вновь, то появляется Тоаст со второго фрагмента (ListInFragment) которое было вызвано раннее, т.е. стартует сперва **onCreate второго фрагмента**, затем только **onCreate активности** и т.д. Т.е., получается, что перед этим **onDestroy активности не вызывается** и сохраняются все фрагменты в FragmentManager, которые были добавлены раннее и мне вновь отображается Toast из второго фрагмета. Хотя такого не должно быть.

Скажите пожалуйста, как исправить эту ситуацию? Или может кто сможет подсказать какой то способ во избежание этого? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если вы делаете вывод о последовательности из логов, то это не факт что это есть на самом деле так. Во вторых, попробуйте удалить приложение из последних, скорее всего приложение не было убито и остается у вас в кеше, соответственно поведение после разворачивания вполне ожидаемо.
Вам стоит изучить тему:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack?hl=ru

Вам нужно чтобы ваш фрагмент не добавлялся в стек.

Или как вариант, просто очищать стек переходов в `onResume()` и тут же вызывать `replaceFragment(new StartFragment());`

Comment: Так у меня фрагменты не добавляются в backstack. А как удалять стек переходов?